# ORACLE SQL: How do I replace NULL with 0 in a Pivot function

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, null-coalescing

How can I replace NULL with 0 in a PIVOT function on ORACLE SQL?
This is the query I'm trying to write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    CUSTOMER_ID AS CUSTOMER_ID,
    CASE  
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '01' THEN 'CAT 01'
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '02' THEN 'CAT 02'
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '03' THEN 'CAT 03'
        ELSE 'OTHER' END AS CATEGORY,
    SUM(ORDERS) AS ORDERS
FROM
    TABLE_01
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    CASE  
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '01' THEN 'CAT_01'
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '02' THEN 'CAT_02'
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '03' THEN 'CAT_03'
        ELSE 'OTHER' END
)
PIVOT
    (
    SUM(ORDERS)
    FOR CATEGORY IN 
        (
        'CAT_01',
        'CAT_02',
        'CAT_03',
        'OTHER'
        )
    )
)
;
```

What I would like is to have a table that when a customer doesn't have any order on a specific category, it would return 0 instead of NULL. like this:

```
CUSTOMER_ID   CAT_01   CAT_02   CAT_03
00001              0      100        0
00002            100        0        0
00003              0        0      100
```

Please, keep in mind that this is a very simplified part of a complex query with several categories and nested queries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to change the `select *` part of your query at the top to specify the columns individually, so that you can wrap them in calls to `nvl`.  You can also use `coalesce` if you like.

```
select customer_id,
       nvl(cat_01, 0) as cat_01, 
       nvl(cat_02, 0) as cat_02, 
       nvl(cat_03, 0) as cat_03,
       nvl(other, 0) as other
from (...
```

Comment: Do you know if I were to add COALESCE to the SUM function it would work? Like this:

PIVOT ( SUM(COALESCE(ORDERS,0)) FOR ...

Comment: It would work, and wrapping each `ORDERS` within `NVL( ..., 0)` would work just as well (they mean the same thing).

Comment: using COALESCE didn't work for me when using it within the aggregate function in PIVOT

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
NVL(CAT_01,0),
NVL(CAT_02,0)
NVL(   CAT_03   
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    CUSTOMER_ID AS CUSTOMER_ID,
    CASE  
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '01' THEN 'CAT 01'
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '02' THEN 'CAT 02'
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '03' THEN 'CAT 03'
        ELSE 'OTHER' END AS CATEGORY,
    SUM(ORDERS) AS ORDERS
FROM
    TABLE_01
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    CASE  
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '01' THEN 'CAT_01'
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '02' THEN 'CAT_02'
        WHEN CATEGORY_CODE = '03' THEN 'CAT_03'
        ELSE 'OTHER' END
)
PIVOT
    (
    SUM(ORDERS)
    FOR CATEGORY IN 
        (
        'CAT_01',
        'CAT_02',
        'CAT_03',
        'OTHER'
        )
    )
)
;
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).